# Do I need to check if lo > hi when building a segment tree

Tags: python, algorithm, tree, segment-tree

The code below is a slightly modified version of popular segment tree code.

My question is why do we need to do the lo > hi check when recursively building the tree, I cannot think of an example where lo will ever be greater than hi since at any point they are equal [2,2] the recursion will not go any deeper.

```
class SegmentNode:

  def __init__(self, start, end):

    self.value = 0
    self.start = start
    self.end = end
    self.left = None
    self.right = None

class SegmentTree:

  def __init__(self, nums):

    self.root = self.buildTree(nums, 0, len(nums)-1)


  def buildTree(self, nums, lo, hi):

    if lo > hi:
      return None

    if lo == hi:
      curr = SegmentNode(lo, hi)
      curr.value = nums[lo]
      return curr

    mid = (lo + hi)//2

    curr = SegmentNode(lo, hi)
    curr.left = buildTree(lo, mid)
    curr.right = buildTree(mid+1, hi)

    curr.value = curr.left.value + curr.right.value

    return curr
```

Comment: If an empty list is passed as `nums` to `__init__` then `lo` will be 0 and `hi` will be -1.

Comment: Awesome thank you very much didnt think about that.

Comment: @mkrieger1 maybe write a proper answer, since it worked. Up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I cannot think of an example where lo will ever be greater than hi

> ```
>   def __init__(self, nums):
>
>     self.root = self.buildTree(nums, 0, len(nums)-1)
>
>
>   def buildTree(self, nums, lo, hi):
>
>     if lo > hi:
>       return None
> ```

One example is:

If an empty list is passed as `nums` to `__init__`, then `buildTree` is called with 0 as `lo` and -1 as `hi`.